# Javascript regular expression to replace word but not within curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some content, for example:

> If you have a question, ask for help on StackOverflow

I have a list of synonyms:

```
a={one typical|only one|one single|one sole|merely one|just one|one unitary|one small|this solitary|this slight}
ask={question|inquire of|seek information from|put a question to|demand|request|expect|inquire|query|interrogate}
```

I'm using JavaScript to:

1. Split synonyms based on `=`
2. Looping through every synonym, if found in content replace with `{...|...}`

The output should look like:

> If you have {one typical|only one|one single|one sole|merely one|just one|one unitary|one small|this solitary|this slight} question, {question|inquire of|seek information from|put a question to|demand|request|expect|inquire|query|interrogate} for help on StackOverflow

Problem:
Instead of replacing the entire word, it's replacing every character found. My code:

```
for(syn in allSyn) {
    var rtnSyn = allSyn[syn].split("=");
    var word = rtnSyn[0];
    var synonym = (rtnSyn[1]).trim();
    if(word && synonym){
        var match = new RegExp(word, "ig"); 
        postProcessContent = preProcessContent.replace(match, synonym);
        preProcessContent = postProcessContent;
    }
}
```

It should replace content word with synonym which should not be in `{...|...}`.

Comment: You received two answers and you gave the same negative reply to both.  Don't you think it might mean you need to rephrase your question?  Please clarify what you want to accomplish.  In particular, how do you define `allSyn`?

Comment: Hi, I did not mean to give any negative reply. I'm just new to this forum. Hers what I'm doing
1:Reading file using ajax.
word={synonym|synonym}
2:var allSyn = (http.responseText.replace(/\s+$/g,"")).split("\n");
3:Getting preProcessedContent from div
4:Looping through allSyn, finding that word in preProcessedContent and replacing the same (regex 'ig')

I just dont want the replaced to get replaced again

Answer (score 3):

When you build the regexps, you need to include [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) at both the beginning and the end to match whole words (beginning and ending with characters from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) only:

```
var match = new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b", "ig");
```

Depending on the specific replacements you are making, you might want to apply your method to individual words (rather than to the entire text at once) matched using a regexp like `/\w+/g` to avoid replacing words that themselves are the replacements for others. Something like:

```
content = content.replace(/\w+/g, function(word) {
    for(var i = 0, L = allSyn.length; i < L; ++i) {
        var rtnSyn = allSyn[syn].split("=");
        var synonym = (rtnSyn[1]).trim();
        if(synonym && rtnSyn[0].toLowerCase() == word.toLowerCase()) return synonym;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't want to replace items already synonym-ized not in {...|...}

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions include something called a "word-boundary", represented by `\b`. It is a zero-width assertion (it just checks something, it doesn't "eat" input) that says in order to match, certain word boundary conditions have to apply. One example is a space followed by a letter; given the string `' X'`, this regex would match it: `/ \bX/`. So to make your code work, you just have to add word boundaries to the beginning and end of your word regex, like this:

```
for(syn in allSyn) {
    var rtnSyn = allSyn[syn].split("=");
    var word = rtnSyn[0];
    var synonym = (rtnSyn[1]).trim();
    if(word && synonym){
        var match = new RegExp("\\b"+word+"\\b", "ig"); 
        postProcessContent = preProcessContent.replace(match, synonym);
        preProcessContent = postProcessContent;
    }
}
```

*[Note that there are two backslashes in each of the word boundary matchers because in javascript strings, the backslash is for escape characters -- two backslashes turns into a literal backslash.]*

Comment: I don't want to replace items already synonym-ized not in {...|...}

Answer (score 0):

For optimization, don't create a new RegExp on each iteration.  Instead, build up a big regex like `[^{A-Za-z](a|ask|...)[^}A-Za-z]` and an hash with a value for each key specifying what to replace it with.  I'm not familiar enough with JavaScript to create the code on the fly.

Note the separator regex which says the match cannot begin with `{` or end with `}`.  This is not terribly precise, but hopefully acceptable in practice.  If you genuinely need to replace words next to `{` or `}` then this can certainly be refined, but I'm hoping we won't have to.